# How Do You Disable/Enable 3G Programatically on Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to code an app for android that needs to enable and disable 3G (move between 2g and 3g), but can't find anything about it...is that possible? Can I get a snippet code or some documentation? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No , it is not possible as just in other mobile platforms not possible..

Comment: Ok... since you can do it in phone preferences...tought it could be possible

Answer (score 0):

Similar question over here from the other side:

[Is it possible to force network traffic through Wifi or the TMobile network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604535/is-it-possible-to-force-network-traffic-through-wifi-or-the-tmobile-network)

Are you talking about moving between Edge and 3g or turning on and off the Wifi.

Comment: I'm trying to move between gprs (2g) and umts (3g). Found out how to enable wifi but not anything about gsm